# Where are the source files in Phone Gap for iOS?

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to look at phone gap after downloading it for iOS to understand how it works, however I can't find hardly any .m files - for example there is PGViewController.h but no PGViewController.m, and searching for any methods within PGViewController.h within the workspace only reveals PGViewController.h in the search results, no .m file, and no implementation that I can find anywhere.

Where is the actual implementation?

In particular I want to look at the implementation of shouldStartLoadWithRequest:, but all there is is this in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
```

Where's the actual meat of the implementation of shouldStartLoadWithRequest - why does it not appear in the Xcode project anywhere that I can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full source can be found at:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios

It is all built into a lib for your convenience on iOS but you can always go get the code.